# memsql/cluster-in-a-box latest image failed to start container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, singlestore

after pulling the latest image this issue accures

on this version everything works fine
`memsql/cluster-in-a-box:centos-7.3.12-2d93725f98-3.2.11-1.11.7`

```
~/workdir/js/master *16 !1 ▓▒░ docker-compose up  memsql                                                            ░▒▓ 2 ✘  15s   2.7.2   08:24:30 
Recreating platform-js_memsql_1 ... done
Attaching to platform-js_memsql_1
memsql_1           | 2021-07-26 05:24:41.431505 Starting Cluster
memsql_1           | Latest errors from MemSQL tracelog:
memsql_1           | 13651863 2021-07-26 05:24:55.333  FATAL: Thread 115111: jumpToUpgradeStep: This node is not managed by a supported tool. Please use a toolbox version at least as new as 1.11.3.
memsql_1           | : Failed to connect to MemSQL: process exited: exit status 1
memsql_1           | Traceback (most recent call last):
memsql_1           |   File "/startup", line 122, in <module>
memsql_1           |     start_cluster()
memsql_1           |   File "/startup", line 86, in start_cluster
memsql_1           |     ctl("start-node", "--all")
memsql_1           |   File "/startup", line 18, in ctl
memsql_1           |     subprocess.check_output(["memsqlctl", "-yj"] + list(args)))
memsql_1           |   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
memsql_1           |     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
memsql_1           | subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['memsqlctl', '-yj', 'start-node', '--all']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

this is my docker-compose setup  using [memsql/cluster-in-a-box](https://hub.docker.com/r/memsql/cluster-in-a-box)

```
  memsql:
    image: memsql/cluster-in-a-box
    volumes:
      - "./init.sql"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      START_AFTER_INIT: Y
      ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
      LICENSE_KEY:*************************
```

OS: `macOs bigSur v11.4`
Docker : `v20.10.7`

also tries as suggested by `Volodymyr Tkachuk`

to run it directly with docker and not working

`docker run -i --init --name memsql -e LICENSE_KEY=$LICENSE -e ROOT_PASSWORD=root -p 3306:3306 -p 8080:8080 memsql/cluster-in-a-box:latest docker start memsql`

'Please use a toolbox version at least as new as 1.11.3.'

isn't toolbox part of the image?
this issue related to 3rd party dependencies or container issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the recent release of SingleStore 7.5 broke upgrade for this Docker image.  We added an upgrade step to the release which requires running `sdb-upgrade`.  We will be fixing this, but in the meantime you have two choices:

1. If you don't care about the data in this image (or you can recreate the data) run `docker-compose up -V` to start 7.5 with an empty data directory.
2. If you do care about the data in this image, modify the entrypoint to run `sdb-upgrade` which should upgrade the data volume, and then you can run the container like normal. You should test this process before running it on your actual image since it is potentially destructive.

Sorry that you ran into this, we will fix the bug soon.